# How to add the Calendar view webpart on the webpart page for SHarePoint Online by Powershell with csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am trying to add the calendar view webpart on the SharePoint Publishing page by powershell and csom, i was able to add it but it was showing all event view instead of calendar view.

Code is added below

```
try{
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
 Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}

catch {
 Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}

$URL="https://netapp.sharepoint.com/sites/AshokTestJive"

$pUsername="pshagadm@netapp.com"
$pPassword = "K3xr7PN6"
$HostName = "https://netapp.sharepoint.com"
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($pUsername,  $(convertto-securestring $pPassword -asplaintext -force))


$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($URL) 
$ctx.Credentials = $Creds

function AddCalenderWebPartToPage ($URL) {
    $pageRelativeUrl = "/Pages/Home.aspx"
    $wpZoneID = "TopRightRow"
    $wpZoneOrder= 1

    $WebPartXml = [xml]''

    try{

        Write-Host "Starting the Process to add the Calender WebPart to the Home Page" -ForegroundColor Yellow

        #Adding the reference to the client libraries. Here I'm executing this for a SharePoint Server (and I'm referencing it from the SharePoint ISAPI directory, 
        #but we could execute it from wherever we want, only need to copy the dlls and reference the path from here        
        Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
        Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

        Write-Host "Getting the page with the webpart we are going to modify" -ForegroundColor Green
        $web = $ctx.Web
        $ctx.Load($web)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        #Using the params, build the page url
        $RelURl=$web.ServerRelativeUrl
        $pageUrl = $RelURl + $pageRelativeUrl
        Write-Host "Getting the page with the webpart we are going to modify: " $pageUrl -ForegroundColor Green

        #Getting the page using the GetFileByServerRelativeURL and do the Checkout
        #After that, we need to call the executeQuery to do the actions in the site
        $page = $ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl($pageUrl);
        $page.CheckOut()
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        try{

        #Get the webpart manager from the page, to handle the webparts
        Write-Host "The page is checkout" -ForegroundColor Green
        $webpartManager = $page.GetLimitedWebPartManager([Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

        Write-Host $WebPartXml.OuterXml

        #Load and execute the query to get the data in the webparts
        Write-Host "Getting the webparts from the page" -ForegroundColor Green
        $ctx.Load($webpartManager);
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        #Import the webpart
        $wp = $webpartManager.ImportWebPart($WebPartXml.OuterXml)


        #Add the webpart to the page
        Write-Host "Add the webpart to the Page" -ForegroundColor Green
        $webPartToAdd = $webpartManager.AddWebPart($wp.WebPart, $wpZoneID, $wpZoneOrder)

        $ctx.Load($webPartToAdd);
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Errors found:`n$_" -ForegroundColor Red

        }
        finally{
            #CheckIn and Publish the Page
            Write-Host "Checkin and Publish the Page" -ForegroundColor Green
            $page.CheckIn("Add the User Profile WebPart", [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
            $page.Publish("Add the User Profile WebPart")
            $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

            Write-Host "The Calender webpart has been added" -ForegroundColor Yellow 

        }   

    }
    catch{
        Write-Host "Errors found:`n$_" -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}

AddCalenderWebPartToPage ($URL)
```